# Frame and coordinates disappear when printing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, grids-graticules

I'm trying to print my map in QGIS 3.18.0 including a zebra frame.

[image: Print Composer Page]

It looks great in the Print layout but when I print it, the zebra frame and coordinates are not there.

[image: Resulting print to PDF. Printing to paper is no better]

Is there a setting or checkbox that I'm missing?

Comment: Try to export as PNG file, it should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going in to the export settings and the output to raster. I have found the pdf output a bit hit and miss.

Comment: Thanks! That got it!